# Is it possible to make an unconditional redirect without return in Visual Basic?

Tags: delphi, basic

I am making a gamebook authoring program in Delphi using paxCompiler. paxCompiler supports Basic, that's why I'm using paxBasic.
In gamebooks you sometimes need to redirect to a different procedure without returning here and continuing execution.
For example:

```
procedure p_woods;
begin
 if Random(2)=1 then go('fight');//the function go is my own, it calls the procedure "p_fight"
 print('You stroll peacefully in the woods');
end;
```

You see that after calling the procedure it should stay there and not return here.
In Pascal there is, however cumbersome, a solution:

```
begin
 go('proc');
 exit;
end;
```

But I can't find any equivalent to this begin..end block in Basic.
My questions:

1. What Basic code would emulate the code above the best?
2. Is it possible to make the Pascal code shorter?

Comment: There is no such thing, afaik, as a `go();` method in pascal or delphi.  Are you thinking of `GoTo`?  It sounds like that's what you want.  Ideally, this is probably not the route you should take, however.  Breaking up your large methods sounds like a better approach.  Take whatever exists below your branching decision and put it into a separate method.

Comment: If you don't want the code below go() to be executed, then don't put it there.... Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: What's wrong with the `else` keyword?  `if Random(2)=1 then go('fight') else print('You stroll peacefully in the woods');`  Job done.

Comment: @J..., Shinkarom is essentially asking for a JMP instruction to use instead of CALL. This `go` function is hypothetical. However, subroutines, whether returned from or not, really don't seem like a good model for the act of reading a book at all, whether it's a [gamebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamebook) or an ordinary linearly navigated book. Shinkarom, you're better off seeking a different solution for your task.

Comment: @RobKennedy I understand what he wants.  JMP doesn't work on its own, though... you can't just jump out of a method without coming back, the stack would explode.  I think this is necessarily an uncircumventable restriction of any procedural, stack-based language.  `Exit;` is the only option.  I agree wholeheartedly that the design of this application needs to be re-examined.  It's not going to turn out well starting like this.

Comment: This kind of application should work with states and transitions

Comment: @J..., you *can* jump out of a function. The Delphi RTL does it in a few places (mostly in the exception-handling code in *System.pas*), and [I've done it myself](https://gist.github.com/rkennedy/1482014#file-tom-pas-L356) (to implement interface methods with non-standard calling conventions).

Comment: @RobKennedy  Yes, but that's surely not in any sort of standard way.  There's micro-managed ASM in there somewhere that's cleaning up the stack, undoubtedly.  Something has to do the job, one way or another, that `end;` or `exit;` would do...  OP is coding a storybook, not an operating system or compiler.  I think we agree that this is not the way forward here...

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what language you are using. As you include the vb.net tag, here is a VB.Net solution for calling a Sub named `Proc` and skipping the rest of the Sub that does the calling.

```vb
Sub SomeMethod()
    'some code that will be executed

    'The following statement is an example of how you are deciding whether to redirect
    If shouldRedirect = True Then
        Proc 'call the Sub named Proc
        Exit Sub 'Exit the SomeMethod Sub
    End If

    'some code that will not be executed after Proc is called
End Sub
```

Comment: I added vb.net because the author of paxCompiler says that "Syntax of Basic language is similar to VB.NET."

Comment: @shinkarom If it is similar enough then the code in my answer should work.

Comment: Is there a way to use such blocks just so, without conditions or loops, just like in Pascal you can insert begin..end anywhere?

Comment: @shinkarom Yes, you can code `Proc` followed by `Exit Sub` anywhere you like in a Sub. But as the_lotus points out in a comment, if you always skip the rest of the code, there is no point in it being there in the first place.

Comment: I figured out what to do. I'll replace go("string") with if true then go('string') exit sub end if. Just had to find a regex for replacing outside of quotes, and I've found it.